# Ghostscript output to file with ESC-P sequences

Tags: drivers, printing, epson, ghostscript, postscript

For a project (printing nanofluids with an Epson printer) I want to see the the code that the computer sends to the printer. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and have an Epson Stylus SX600FW printer.
Using Ghostscript 9.18 I am trying to print a simple file `test.ps` and I want to obtain the output file that is being send to the printer. This file should contain some ESC/P sequences if I am right.

I tried to obtain such a file using:

```
gs -sDevice=epson -sOutputFile=test1output test1.ps
```

Whatever I try, I can't find the output file anywhere, so I doubt it is even created. Then next if I have the output file, how can I read the ESC/P sequences? Thanks in advance!